# LinkedIn Profile API v2: Cannot retrieve List of profiles

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to retrieve some information about other people from the LinkedIn Profile API, following the instructions at [Retrieve Other Member's Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api#retrieve-other-members-profile).

When calling

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people?ids=List((id:<id1>),(id:<id2>))&oauth2_access_token=<access_token_string>
```

I receive the error:

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 0,
    "message": "Invalid query parameters passed to request",
    "status": 400
}
```

However, If I tried to retrieve information from one person at a time, the API returns the details correctly.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/(id:id1)?oauth2_access_token=<access_token_string>
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/(id:id2)?oauth2_access_token=<access_token_string>
```

Both the calls above work, but the List call on the same id's, with the same access token does not work.

Note: I am passing in `X-RestLi-Protocol-Version:2.0.0` as a request header.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who's run into this issue, you should test using curl if you're using Postman or a similar tool.

As per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api

> Note that URNs included in the URL params must be URL encoded when using Restli 2.0. For example, urn:li:ugcPost:12345 would become urn%3Ali%3AugcPost%3A12345. Other parts of the params should not be encoded. Postman or similar API tools may not support these types of calls. Testing with curl is recommended if you encounter a 400 error with message Invalid query parameters passed to request.